# What is the best way to run python scripts in the background of Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, background

I created a python script that work as a bot for instagram (using selenium).
Currently I have 5 profile running, for each of them I have all the files stored in folders (called with the name of the ig profile) and for each profile I have a screen where I can see the "log" of each program.
But now, 5 profile are difficult to manage and sometimes also a little messy.
Is there a way to see the log of all 5 scripts in a unique window? 
I'm open also to another way to run the scripts in the background, maybe not "screen" but something else.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go the clean way and if you think this will get bigger, you might want to have a look towards Django and Celery.

You can create a web interface, so that you can monitor any way you like.

And you can have cron jobs with Celery so that your bot is always on, or has recurring tasks, etc...

More info on their respective docs, as usual. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html